# GWT: How can i add css style for tabpanel in gwt WebApplication

Tags: gwt

I have created GWTWebApplication , I have added one tabpanel and added htmltab penels.
now i want to change of tabpanel background style but  i could not ,even i try to add decarated panel that case also same.

if i create GWT Javaproject that case it adds some predefine css style .but in webapplication project noting defult css styles

This is my code

```
TabPanel tabPanel = new TabPanel();
HTMLPanel hPanle1 =new HTMLPanel("");
HTMLPanel hPanle2 =new HTMLPanel("");
tabPanel.add(hpanel1,HPanel);
tabPanel.add(hpanel2,HPanel2);
```

My requirement is to change the tabbar background color only,and when i select my should be heligheted .
please give me response as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a way to change the background of the active tab. You can accomplish this with GWT's built-in classes that it applies automatically to the active nav items.

Just put this in your CSS somewhere:

```
.tabpanel-activeNavItem {
    background: red;
}
```

You can also look at the classes `TabPanelResources` and `TabPanelStyle`, and the css file `tabpanel.css` for details on the default styles.  To understand more about how GWT handles CSS, read their [CSS Resource Documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResource)